# Is this too vague? : What are the physical limitations that I have to keep in mind, when writing about nanobots?

Tags: discussion

Is this too vague?

> **What are the physical limitations that I have to keep in mind, when writing about nanobots?**
>
> Like maximum effective speed, waste heat minimums, computation ability minimums, etc.

Should I move to Worldbuilding, or does this have enough physics content to count as a Physics question?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, I'd say it's too broad. But more than that, it's not actually about physics, so it's completely off topic for us.

Anyway, given that your concern seems to be *writing* about nanobots, rather than building or designing them, Worldbuilding is probably the place to start. You would have to ask them whether they consider it too broad for that site.